# MapView in RecyclerView dispalys wrong map in certain scroll position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-maps-android-api-2, android-databinding

I use `MapView` inside my `recyclerview` items to display info about a city which the item is about, and I can't figure out how to fix binding issues.
When current item is at the top of the viewport, the map is correct: [image: Proper map displayed]

But when another item is at the top of the viewport, that is what happens:[image: Wrong map displayed]

As you can see, map displays Salzburg instead of Edinburgh because Salzburg is at the top of `recyclerview` viewport.

My `ViewHolder` class:

```
inner class WeatherViewHolder(
        private val binding: ItemWeatherBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
        binding.root
    ), OnMapReadyCallback {

        lateinit var gMap: GoogleMap
        init {
            binding.apply {
                // Other binging here...

                with(map) {
                    onCreate(null)
                    getMapAsync(this@WeatherViewHolder)
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(weather: Weather) {
            binding.apply {
                //Other binding here...

                setMapLocation()

            }
        }

        override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
            Log.v("Maps", "OnReady")
            MapsInitializer.initialize(superFragment.activity)
            gMap = googleMap
            with(gMap.uiSettings) {
                isZoomControlsEnabled = false
                isCompassEnabled = false
                isMapToolbarEnabled = false
                isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                isRotateGesturesEnabled = false
                isScrollGesturesEnabled = false
                isTiltGesturesEnabled = false
                isZoomGesturesEnabled = false
            }
            binding.map.onResume()
            setMapLocation()
        }
        private fun setMapLocation() {
            if (!::gMap.isInitialized) return
            Log.v("Maps", "setting location")
            val weather = getItem(adapterPosition)
            with(gMap) {
                moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(weather.latitude, weather.longitude), 10f))
                mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
            }
            superFragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                repository.getInfo { response ->
                    gMap.addTileOverlay(/*setting my tiles here*/)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried calling `setMapLocation()` only to an item which is currently expanded (as I use expandable layout here), but it only led to more confusing behavior.

The question here is: how can I fix this behavior and display correct map regardless of `recyclerview`'s scroll position?

Comment: Its better if you use [LiteMode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) in `RecyclerView` . you can go through the link there is also sample specific to `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I am aware of that, but in my case I need TileOverlay feature, which is not supported in Lite Mode. If there is a way to implement this without using so much resources, I will happily consider that.